# CA1031 - catch a more specific exception type or rethrow exception

Tags: c#, exception, code-analysis

I understand the code analysis error, but it feels weird why error occurs on this code:

```
public bool IsCurrentLicenseValid()
{     
  int licenseStatusCode = 0;

  try
  {
    int licenseStatusCode = this.GetLicenseStatus();

    if (licenseStatusCode > 0)
    {
      return true;
    }

     return false;
  }
  catch (NalpeironException)
  // catch (NalpeironException ex), but now: the variable ex is declared but never used
  {
    DiagnosticsService.Instance.Trace(
      TraceFilters.Services, 
      "NalpeironLicensingService.IsCurrentLicenseValid", 
      $"License status indicates error '{licenseStatusCode}'");

    // the error goes away if I use ex in the message (i.e. ex.Message)

    return false;
  }
}
```

I caught **specific exception** in the catch statement, I just don't want to use exception message or some other exception property. Is the only solution here to suppress this message? Or should I use some exception property or method?

The NalpeironException extends Exception, here's the code:

```
public class NalpeironException : Exception
{
    private Enum errorId;

    public NalpeironException(Enum errorId, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.errorId = errorId;
    }

    public Enum ErrorId
    {
        get { return this.errorId; }
        set { this.errorId = value; }
    }

    public bool IsEqualId(Enum errorId)
    {
        return this.ErrorId.GetType() == errorId.GetType() && this.ErrorId.Equals(errorId);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The proper way would be to use NalpeironException message in diagnostics service. In order words to log the exception message. I'm afraid I can't do that because the code was already written by someone else and the application was shipped out.

Comment: Do you not want to provide `NalpeironException` as an inner exception? (I can see why you might not want to)

Comment: It is just tripped up by this code being so thoroughly uninterested in the exception object.  It is a code smell, you only know that "it did not work", you can't know exactly why.  That ErrorId property looks pretty important to diagnose the why.

Comment: It appears that only `this.GetLicenseStatus();` can throw the exception. But when it does, `licenseStatusCode` will always be `0`. So why trace it. `errorId` would probably make more sense to trace. imho

Comment: The problem is that the code was already written by someone else, therefore I'm afraid that I could break something. Although it would make sense to add ex.ErrorId to diagnostics. This would solve the problem.

Comment: `licenseStatusCode` is declared in the `try` block. How is it being referenced inside of the `catch`? Seems weird, perhaps an instance field? Otherwise if this was working it seems you'd only get a zero and that details of the Exception (`ErrorId`) are more "interesting" and worth logging/tracing

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes sorry, I moved int licenseStatusCode before try statement. Visual Studio Code analysis suggested to put in in the try block, because I changed catch block.

Comment: Thnx Hans Passant, Thomas K and pinkfloysx33 for valid comments.